# Webseal junction name change after some seconds

Tags: webseal

I have angular2 app that is called from webseal server.
I'm getting the junction name value from the cookie: "IV_JCT"
The problem is that the junction name value is changed after some seconds from: "%2Fempsvcs" to the "real" junction name.
To solve this issue I added sleep for 5 seconds before getting the junction name.
Any ideas why it is working like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The IV_JCT cookie is set using a block of javascript that is injected into the client response on each request for a junction where scripting support (-s) is enabled.  The value is set to the name of the junction where the request originated from.  Check your WebSEAL request logs and you will see a call being made to /realjunction (whatever that name is) at some point during the client communicating with WebSEAL.  Using the IV_JCT cookie within the browser is not an accurate way to determine the context (junction) being used because it could change if the client requests something on a different junction, and then you read the value after that request occurs.